# What CSS command is used to place the parent level of a menu under the children when they are displayed?

Tags: css

I have a Drupal superfish menu with three levels. After upgrading the module I found that the children no longer appear over top of the parents.  What setting defines the order they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing the code, but `z-index` is the rule that is used to determine `stack order`

It would be something like this

Give

```
.sf-menu li{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

and

```
.sf-menu li li{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2000;
}
```

The rule with the greater `z-index` number appears on top of the one that is lower.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the structure

for example, if you have a:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>
  <ul><li>sub 3</li></ul>
 </li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

You could hide children ul like:

```
ul li ul { display:none;}
```